# How many values are in sequence from an array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to find how many values, in an array, are in sequence without sorting.

For Instance, if I have.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 } //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 are in sequence
int value = HighestSequence(arr);
//value prints 7

int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9 } //1, 2, 3, 4 are in sequence
int value = HighestSequence(arr);
//value prints 4

int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 } //0, 1, 2 is in sequence
int value = HighestSequence(arr);
//value prints 3
```

Comment: Shouldn't your second example output 4 instead of 3? 1, 2, 3, 4 are in sequence.

Comment: Good Point, i should of proofread.

Comment: What is your actual _question_? What you've posted so far is just a requirements statement. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise, detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this out. I got the results of (7,4,3). Although Peter is correct about StackOverflow you should give your attempt and say your issue not just ask for an answer. I only provided it because it was a neat challenge.

```
var set1 = new [] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 }; 
var result1 = HighestSequence(set1);

var set2 = new[] { 0, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9 };
var result2 = HighestSequence(set2);

var set3 = new [] { 0, 1, 2 };
var result3 = HighestSequence(set3);

public int HighestSequence(int[] values)
{
    IList<int> sequenceCounts = new List<int>();

    var currentSequence = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == (values.Length - 1)) //End edge case
        {
            if (values[i] - values[i - 1] == 1)
            {
                currentSequence++;
                sequenceCounts.Add(currentSequence);
            }
        }
        else if ((values[i] + 1) == values[i + 1])
        {
            currentSequence++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentSequence++;
            sequenceCounts.Add(currentSequence);
            currentSequence = 0;
            continue;
        }
        sequenceCounts.Add(currentSequence);
    }
    return sequenceCounts.Max();
}
```

Comment: @AlexMoreno, out of curiosity, what made you choose this solution over mine ? Is it because I'm using Linq ?

Comment: because you weren't using linq. comments were right i should of added my version, and an example of it, but it didn't occur to me at the time. Linq doesn't work on .NET versions older then 3.0, i just didn't remember how to do it without using it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify what should happen if there is more than one subsequence in order, but I've assumed there will be only one.

Try this:

```
int length = 1;
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9 }; //0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 are in sequence
//value prints 7
List<int> temp = arr.Zip(arr.Skip(1), (i1, i2) => length += (i2 - i1 == 1 ? 1 : 0)).ToList();
```

`Length` will contain the number of integers in sequence where arr[n] == arr[n+1] - 1

Cheers

EDIT:

In the case where there is more than one subsequence that is ordered such that arr[n] == arr[n+1] - 1, we'd need to decide how to handle it.

One way would be to reset the length when we find a value that doesn't meet the criteria:

```
arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 9 }; //Possible bug ?
length = 1;
temp = arr.Zip(arr.Skip(1), (i1, i2) =>
{
    if(i2 - i1 == 1)
    {
        length++;
    }
    else
    {
        length = 1;
    }
    return i1;
}).ToList();
```

But then this will not consider the "longest" subsequence, it will return the length of the "last" subsequence in the sequence.

The OP should specify what action he wants in such cases.

EDIT #2:

If we want to have the longest subsequence, then this could be used:

```
arr = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9 }; //Possible bug ?
length = 1;
int longest = length;
temp = arr.Zip(arr.Skip(1), (i1, i2) =>
{
    if (i2 - i1 == 1)
    {
        if (++length > longest)
            longest = length;
    }
    else
    {
        length = 1;
    }
    return i1;
}).ToList();
```

Caching the longest ordered subsequence length. Then use `longest` instead of `length` as the result.

EDIT #3:

Edits #1 & 2 should now contain the appropriate solution. I was obviously trying to come up with a solution to a comment from a user too quickly and I didn't realize that the current code in my VS solution was different than the code I posted here.

It is to be mentioned that the OP didn't have those additional constraints, and that I did mention right from the get go that my solution didn't address those additional constraints.

Nonetheless, it was an interesting problem to solve ;-)

Cheers

Comment: Did you test your solution? I mean not only monotonic sequence

Comment: I tested my solution against the dataset provided by the OP, which includes a non-monotonic sequence (second array of values). Why do you ask, did you find a problem ?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking because I liked your solution for being concise and wanted to vote up but run it and see it's not working :( Try `{ 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 9 }` and see `5`. It's pity

Comment: Ahh, well, that's why I mentioned at the beginning of my answer "You don't specify what should happen if there is more than one subsequence in order, but I've assumed there will be only one.". This is exactly the case I had in mind since there is more than one ordered subsequence in this sequence. There'd need to be a way to reset the counter. I'm sure it would be easy enough. Let me think about it for a minute or two ;)

Comment: `{ 0, 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7 }` returns `3` :( You would fail an interview :)

Comment: Well, luckily for me this is not an interview, this is a voluntary Q&A site, where I use my free time to help fellow programmers, so if you're unhappy with one of my answers, downvote it and be done with it. Nitpicking and trying to find examples outside of the parameters of the OP is not really constructive.